# How to discharge the pn junction capacitance

Tags: diodes

[image]

Suppose the pn junction is reverse biased, so the width of the depletion region is large as shown. Now I disconnect the battery. What happens to the ions in the depletion region ? I think the depletion region tries to get back to the width corresponding to its barrier potential. But I have difficulty in visualizing how exactly this happens. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How would you discharge a regular capacitor?

Comment: By joining the ends with a wire ? I feel I cannot do that to the diode because the extra charge is trapped in the covalent bond in the depletion region. Shouldn't I wait for those ions to generate electron-hole pairs ?

Comment: Also I feel that the discharging happens automatically without me having to short... Somehow the ions give up their charge and pass through the junction... I'm not really sure, this is exactly the trouble I have visualizing..

Comment: The bias being removed, the charge moves into the formerly depleted region.   It just requires the positive charge on one side to attract the negative charge on the other.   There's still a depletion region, but it's narrower.

Answer (score 1):

It self-discharges in much less than a second usually.

Ir at Vr rises with many factors usually power rating. Similarity Cr rises with Pd rating but may drop with high Vr ratings for diodes and rises in Schottky diodes over Silicon diodes.

Consider: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FJ/FJH1100.pdf

"Ultra low,leakage signal diode"

It is 2pF at Vr = 0V and Ir is 3pA at Vr=5V.

We expect C at Vr=5V to be much less , let's say <1pF.  thus Rr=5V/3pA and C<1pF so RC=T < 5/3 seconds

---

Now let's look at the body diode in a 500A IGBT.

http://www.pwrx.com/pwrx/docs/cm450dx-24s1_e.pdf. (see note 1)

- then see Qrr = 12 μC (typ.) at 3.4V from turnon to off
- then see Ices= 1 mA (max)at Vce=Vces=1000V with Vgs=O

  - since C=Q/V and Rces=Vces/Ices=1MΩ
  - but C(1000V) will be about <1% of C(3.4V) {roughly} and thus  RcesCs<1M12μ*1%*C/1kV=12ks which seems wrong